# Write Unicode characters to & from standard output stream

Tags: java

I need to reassign the standard output stream to a jTextArea, which I did as follows:

```
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new StdOutput()));

    class StdOutput extends OutputStream {
        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            jTextArea1.append(String.valueOf((char) b));
        }
    }
```

However, I have some special characters written to the stream but they don't get displayed properly - e.g. a degree sign comes out as two chineese characters.

I thought this may have to do with the width of the `char` type and truncating the `int` type to 16 bits, so not all special characters will be displayed properly. However, the degree sign is only `0x00B0` so it should fit well within a `char`. What I get instead of `0x00B0` is two characters - `0xFFC2` & `0xFFB0`.

I also tried masking `b` with `0xFFFFFFFF` and assigning different encodings to the `PrintStream` instance, but had no success. What am I missing?

Comment: `OutputStream` is for bytes, `Writer` is for characters.  Just writing an `int` wouldn't work; it's going to output each byte as its own char rather than combining the two bytes.

Comment: Use [this ctor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.OutputStream,boolean,java.nio.charset.Charset))

Comment: BTW `"°".getBytes()` results in `[-62, -80]` (aka `[0xC2, 0xB0]`) as UTF-8 is probably the used enccoding and `\u00B0` is encoded by that bytes - [Wikipedia]: "The first 128 code points (ASCII) need one byte. The next 1,920 code points need two bytes to encode, ..."

Comment: By the way, `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters. Make a habit of using Unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers instead: `Character.toString( b )`. For [DEGREE SIGN](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b0/index.htm), `Character.toString( 176 )`. See that code run [at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/yJai53).

Comment: Thanks all for pointing me in the right direction, indeed I was trying to write characters using a byte stream, so any integer not fitting within the byte type was getting split. I managed to get a working solution using Charset decoder and a ByteBuffer, will post it below.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must specify the character encoding when creating the `PrintStream`, because when you append the value of `(char) b` to the `jTextArea1`, it assumes the default character encoding of your system and not be able to display certain characters properly!

For the [`PrintStream` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.OutputStream,boolean,java.nio.charset.Charset)), pass the parameter for [`Charset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html), such as [`StandardCharsets.UTF_8`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_8).

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new StdOutput(), true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

class StdOutput extends OutputStream {
    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        jTextArea1.append(String.valueOf((char) b));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was one of the first things I tried but it did not work. The problem here is that the byte stream is still being used to write int-long characters per every write(int b) call.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the people who commented on my original post, I came up with something that works for my situation:

```
    bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(500);
    cs = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    dc = cs.newDecoder();

    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new StdOutput(), true));

class StdOutput extends OutputStream {
    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        if (b == '\n') {
            bb.put((byte)'\n');
            bb.rewind();
            jTextArea1.append(dc.decode(bb).toString());
            bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(500);
        } else {
            bb.put((byte) b);
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously that is pretty clumsy and only works for my locale and if I put a single string of a known length per write call, so if anyone can suggest a more elegant solution for writing characters to the standard output stream - I would highly appreciate it!

Comment: What was your particular motivation for remapping `System.out`?

Comment: @g00se I have a large TextArea where the app displays status codes and other messages while it runs, so I thought redirecting the standard output to it would make it more convinient for diagnostic purposes e.g. exceptions display, use of System.out.print() in the code etc.  Looking purely at the overhead it added and other issues I faced I would not use it in production code. Was still worth the effort to see if it was possible at all and learn something new.